# Move data from one gridview to another for edit and update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-5

I am working on a school project to create a web portal that allows butchers to sign up and sell their meat online. now I have created two girdviews, one that i will use for my default catalog(displays products to allow butchers to select their products when creating their catalog)and the other one that will get items from gridview1 to gridview2. now in gridview2 i want butchers to be able to select and edit products and then save them to their own ButcherProducts table which has StoreID, ProductID, Price, Quantity. now i can get items from gridview1 to gridview2 but i am struggling to put the edit functionality so butchers can edit and save. here is my sample code. I am using entity framework code first.

Select Category:

```
        <td> <asp:GridView ID="Catalog" runat="server" 

            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            ItemType="DataAccess.Product"

            AllowSorting="false"
             DataKeyNames="ProductID"


            SelectMethod="GetCatalog">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID"
            SortExpression="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name"
            SortExpression="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"
            SortExpression="Description" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID"
            SortExpression="CategoryID" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">

         <ItemTemplate>
                <%#:Item.Category.CategoryName %>
            </ItemTemplate>


        </asp:TemplateField>

           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
             <img src="..Checkout/images/<%#:Item.ImagePath%>"
                                            width="20" height="25" border="1" />
                     </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Products">

           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
```

C# code behind:

```
List<product> tempIDList = new List<product>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    private MeatbyMobileContext _db = new MeatbyMobileContext();
    public IQueryable<category> GetCatalogCategories()
    {

        return _db.Categories;

    }

    public IQueryable<product> GetCatalog([Control]int? category)
    {
        var query = _db.Products.Select(p => p);
        if (category.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.CategoryID == category.Value);

        }
        return query;

    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    for (int z = 0; z < Catalog.Rows.Count; z++)
    {
       MeatbyMobileContext db = new MeatbyMobileContext();


        CheckBox chk =  (CheckBox)Catalog.Rows[z].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {

          int dKey = Convert.ToInt32( Catalog.DataKeys[z].Value);

            Product product = (from c in db.Products
                               where c.ProductID.Equals(dKey)
                            select c).SingleOrDefault();

             tempIDList.Add(product );





        }

    }

    GridView2.DataSource = tempIDList;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the edit item template.It was specifically created for editing.In your grid view  create corresponding edit item templates for the stuff which needs to be edited like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">

       <ItemTemplate>
     <%#:Item.Category.CategoryName %>
        </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox  ID="txtCategoryEdit"  runat="server"  Text='<%#Bind("CategoryName")%>' /  >
           <EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in your row updating event locate this textbox like this

```
 protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
       TextBox txtCategoryEdit = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("FieldEditTextBox")  ;

            // put your update logic here 
    }
```

Also bind your Gridview2 to an object datasource and specify a dummy  update method.This will save you a lot of work.

Comment: tanx. what i needed was to first save the items in gridview2 to db then enable edit in the gridview aspx page then use the tryupdate method with code first.